# MVC with WCF service design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

Being new to MVC, and WCF (somewhat), I'd like to ask a design question. I have an MVC application, with a simple screen. I need to call a WCF service, which returns a reply object type. To separate the WCF calls from my MVC app, I have created a `ServiceProxy` dll, which exposes a method called `RegisterWithService`, passing it an IP address.

So, MVC app, calls

```
ServiceProxy.RegisterWithService(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx);
```

The method then creates a `RegistrationRequest` object, and sends that to the WCF service. The reply (a `RegisterResponce` object) replies with an object.

My question is, is it OK to pass that object back to the MVC controller to deal with, or should I create some form of DTO... so that the `ServiceProxy` creates a new object type (maybe, `RegistrationDTO`, which has the same fields as the WCF reply object, and passes that back to the MVC app? That, I guess, makes the MVC non-reliant on the WCF objects... so a change in the service contract would only cause a change in the proxy class I created - leaving the MVC app segregated.

Does that seem like a good design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that 2 levels of objects are enough:

1. Domain models (coming from your WCF service)
2. View models (specific to the MVC application)

So you could use the service proxy interface that was generated for you when you imported the WCF service definition as repository layer. This interface will return your data contracts which will represent the domain models. The Controller will be responsible for calling various methods on this interface and mapping the domain models to view models that will be passed to the view.

For example:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    private readonly IServiceProxy service;
    public HomeController(IServiceProxy service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        SomeDataContract domainModel = this.service.Get(id);
        MyViewModel model = Mapper.Map<SomeDataContract, MyViewModel>(domainModel);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Of course if your application gets more complex you could introduce an additional abstraction layer and DTOs.

Comment: This would mean the WCF service objects are exposed to the MVC application. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, they will be exposed. Otherwise how do you even think to consume this WCF service?

Comment: That's a valid question, but my plan was to use a Service Proxy class, which exposes basic methods, and does all the service related work... and then returns... something ... to my MVC app. You're suggesting I return the WCF service objects, which means, I will need to have reference to the WCF service in my MVC app, which I was hoping to avoid - although, it seems the endpoints need to be in the MVC app, and passed TO the proxy class... so.... I'm stuck. :)

Comment: No, you don't need to have any reference. You could generate a client side proxy from the metadata using the svcutil.exe for example. Or just the import service reference in Visual Studio. This will generate the client side proxy classes that will allow you to consume the service. It will contain the data and the service contracts. No need to reference anything. Of course if the service changes, your client will break and there's not much you could do about it. Your client will always be dependent on the service no matter how hard you try.